# I can't install mysql on ubunut 20.04

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-20.04

i have to install mysql-server for my project. but while i install with `sudo apt install mysql-server` it say's `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)` and `E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`. i'd try to search the solving method but is has no change. thanks for any help

(edit)

and also i get this error `The following packages have unmet dependencies: mysql-server-core-8.0 : Depends: libprotobuf-lite23 (>= 3.12.4) but it is not installable`

Comment: For E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend , you can use sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Comment: for installing mysql  use this link - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: thank's for the advice:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that another process is updating on your Linux machine.

You can check what processes are locking the file by running:

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

and kill the PID indicated by the command. If no processes are indicated by the command above, the easiest and fastest way to solve the issue is by rebooting your machine.

After the reboot rerun the command:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

If the error persists, delete the `lock-frontend` file and reshot the command above.

Comment: thanks for advice, i'd try it the same way before and still get those error

Comment: did you try deleting the lock-frontend file after reboot?

Comment: i do, it's working for now. Thanks for helping me mr pasquale.

Comment: Your welcome. I edited the answer above. Please accept it in order to help other people having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some active apt process already?

check it:
ps aux | grep -I apt

then
sudo kill 'busy process id'

or you can kill all apt processes:
sudo killall apt apt-get

and try install MySQL again

In other case you have a locked file, just check it:

sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

then you try to remove lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

and reconfigure dpkg

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt update

Comment: hi, i try your method and now the error says

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-core-8.0 : Depends: libprotobuf-lite23 (>= 3.12.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

i'll try to search this error. thanks for advice

Comment: Try to update packages 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
Then try fix packages
apt-get autoremove